# Alias Queue in Cluster with queue type "cluster"

Tags: ibm-mq

In cluster environment I have deleted a remote queue say "REMOTEtoTNSERVER". But i could see the same queue exists as type "cluster" with several instance. How can i delete them? I checked on repository the queue manager entry for that remote queue is no longer exists.

Please suggest your answers.

Thanks,
Vignesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume QMgrs A, B, C, and REPOS1 and REPOS2 in the cluster.  If you are working on A and delete `REMOTEtoTNSERVER` and still see it as a cluster queue, then it is defined somewhere else in the cluster, probably on B and C.

If you go to the repository QMgrs, they too will show the queues that are on B & C and advertised to the cluster.  The only way to get rid of these is to sign onto the B & C QMgrs and delete the queues or remove them from the cluster.

To determine which QMgrs in the cluster host the clustered instances of these queues, use the `DIS QCLUSTER()` command from the A QMgr or either of the repositories.  This will tell you which QMgrs host an instance of a clustered queue so that you can go there and delete them.